# Find $E(N)$ - probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Experiment $E$ is to toss a fair coin twice. Success is $HH$. $E$ is repeated $20$ times and $N =\frac{20S}{20}$ is the fraction of the $20$ trials that were successes. Find $E(N)$.

How do i do this? I'm stuck on this problem and i could really use a step by step explanation.

Comment: Please show where you're stuck. This will increase your chances to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The coin is fair, so $P(H)=0.5$. Since it seems reasonable to assume that the two consecutive coin tosses are independent of each other, $P(E)$ can be calculated as follows: $$P(E)=P(HH)=0.5 \times 0.5=0.25.$$

From then on, we have a binomial distribution with $n=20$ and $p=0.25$. We know that the expected value of a binomial distribution is $n \times p$. Hence $$E(20S)=20 \times 0.25=5.$$ So we have that $E(N)=E\left(\frac{20S}{20}\right)=\frac{E(20S)}{20}=\frac{5}{20}=\frac{1}{4}$

Or, you could have noticed that $P(N)=P(E)$, and then have stopped after the calculation of $P(E)$ since the expectation of the fraction of successes is independent of the number of times that you perform the experiment.